# Runtime Error 201 at fpc

Tags: runtime-error, pascal, freepascal

i have been writing a game about guessing numbers and i have to seperate a 4 digit number into its digits and put digits into an array.However that section keeps giving me runtime error 201 using fpc.However when i use ideone.com it gives me what i want.I can't figure out.can it be a bug?Sorry for my English.

```
program game;
var
    number : array [1..4] of integer;
    z, i, j: integer;
    number_4digit: integer;
begin
     readln(number_4digit);
     for i := 4 downto 1 do begin
        j := i;
        z := number_4digit;
        while z > 10 do begin
            z := z div 10;
     end;   
     number[5-i] := z;
     repeat
           z := z * 10;
           j := j - 1;
     until j = 1;
     number_4digit:= number_4digit - z;
     write(number[5-i], ' ');  
end;    
end.
```

Edit:I solved the problem.Thanks for Marco van de Voort.

```
repeat
      z := z * 10;
      j := j - 1;
until j = 1;
```

I changed this section into this.

```
while j > 1 do begin
 z := z * 10;
     j := j - 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. J is always 1 after the for loop.
2. Then in the repeat loop it is decremented (to j=0).
3. Which is unequal to 1, so it decreases once more to -1 till -32768 then it rolls over to 32767
4. then further 32767 to 1.

In summary the repeat is done 65536 +/-1 times. The meaning of the J variable is not clear to me from the code. Comment more.

Comment: I used j there as a counter.That code of section is for digit value.I solved the problem using while loop instead of repeat-until loop.So inequality of j is avoided.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime error 201 is a range check error.

Compile with `-gl` and you will see where the program crashes in the runtime error. It's line 16 (`z := z * 10;`), meaning that your `z` is overflowing. Note that `integer` is a signed 16 bit type in FPC (maximum 2^15 - 1 = 32767).

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I'd forgotten that FPC still defaults to 16-bit signed integers by default; I use Delphi, which by default uses 32-bit integers on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: And the reason why it is overflowing is because j = 1 when the for i loop finishes. So when it enters the repeat-until loop, it will loop, I guess 65534 times - so the program is attempting to multiple z by 10^65534.

Comment: Well, why does it loop 65534?Is j = 1 supposed to loop 12 times?.Sorry for asking but i'm a beginner for both programming and pascal.

Comment: I know it might be too late, but That's why: at the before your repeat loop your i = 1. Then, you subtract 1 from it, making it 0. And, since 0 is not equal to one, program keeps subtracting. And there are 65534 possible integer values (from -2^8 to 2^8-1), i changes through every possible value.